# When Back from Camera App by "Discrad" Crash

Tags: android, crash, android-camera-intent

Activity Call to camera App (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE - Ident).

1. If the user, After taking Picture, hit "Save" button - back to the calling activity , Resume it -   OK.
2. If the user hit back - back to the calling activity, Resume it  - OK
3. If the user hit "Discard" button, then Back - crash. the calling activity
   is trying to recreat itself instead Resume.

OS: Android 4.4.2   Device: Samsung Galaxy S5

```
            case R.id.camera:


/**************************/
/** Camera               **/
/**************************/

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {


            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);


    }

        return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I simplify the code to the minimum, Still The behavior like I described.

Comment: ...what? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: "the calling activity is trying to recreat itself" -- while you may only be seeing it on discard with this camera app, you will encounter this in other cases. Your process may be terminated while it is in the background and the camera app is in the foreground. Your app needs to be able to handle this. We cannot give you more specifics without a stack trace and the code that pertains to that stack trace.

Comment: Well, It is either Android version or Device. Other Device + Android 5, Working perfect......